# Remap root for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, url-routing

I have installed a Ruby on Rails app on an internal server and need the application root to look like a directory.

Campus IT has arranged so that all requests directed to http://myinstitution.edu/mydepartment/servicename are routed to http://myinternalserver.edu/

This causes an error: No route matches [GET] "/mydepartment/servicename"

I have tried modifying routes.rb:

```
match "/mydepartment/servicename", to: "home#index", via: [:get, :post]
```

but that leads to the error: undefined local variable or method `root_url' for ...

I added

```
get '/mydepartment/servicename' => redirect("/")
```

but this causes all requests to be redirected to http://myinstitution.edu/# rather than the directory that gets the request sent to my server

How do I make it look like my actual service is at a directory base? I have not used RoR before. Thanks.

Original routes.rb before I messed with it:
This is the original before I messed with it:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: "catalog#index"
  blacklight_for :catalog
  Blacklight::Marc.add_routes(self)
  devise_for :users
end
```

Comment: Could you post your routes.rb?

Comment: Original routes.rb before edits added to question

Comment: what's your current default host? http://myinstitution.edu I presume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `routes.rb` you could use scope to make it easier to define routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: "catalog#index"
  blacklight_for :catalog
  Blacklight::Marc.add_routes(self)
  devise_for :users

  scope "/mydepartment/servicename" do
    match '/', to: "home#index", via: [:get, :post]
    # ... more routes
  end
end
```

You still need your `root to:` to point to a valid controller and action. The error you were getting, `undefined local variable or method 'root_url' for ...` is due to this clause missing in your `routes.rb`.

Since you're using Devise, it's routes will also need to be adjusted. See [How To: Change the default sign_in and sign_out routes](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes) for more info.